# VNC no longer working after update

Tags: raspberrypi, vnc, 21.10

I recently updated my ubuntu to 21.10, and did so using VNC viewer on on phone to click on the upgrade etc.

I woke this morning to make sure my media server was still working (it is) but was unable to view my pi via VNC, receiving this error message:

"The port on which the computer is listening for a connection could not be contacted".

Is there a way to fix this or possibly roll back to to the previous version?

I finally had my set-up how I want it and with 1 upgrade I can no longer view my pi screen.

I use a dummy plug to imitate that there's a screen attached as I had issues viewing previously unless a screen was attached.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You did not say what version of Ubuntu you had previously but it could be due to Wayland now being the default display (previously it was Xorg/X11). Wayland (at least when I first tried to use it) seems to break VNC and any sort of screen/keyboard/mouse sharing software like X2X or Barrier which I was using. So I just went back to using Xorg/X11. You could try that, See here: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-enable-disable-wayland-on-ubuntu-20-04-desktop

Comment: I'm not 100% sure to be honest, pretty sure it was 20.04.

Comment: Ok, so feel kinda stupid now. I just had to go into my settings and turn screen sharing on. It's slower than it was before but it works again. Sorry.

Comment: @Muzbar How did you do that through the command line>

Comment: @SachinMotwani I didn't do it via command line, I had to connect to a monitor to access the settings.

Comment: @Muzbar In that case, it is not possible for me. Mine is a remote server.